# Swapping images on Asp.net page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to swap images front/rear `onclick()`. When I click the image, I can see the rear image, but when I click on the rear image, I can't see the front. I am passing the front and rear paths from the server code:

```
<script>


var theImg = null, theImgPath = null;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    theImg = document.getElementById("imgCh_Front");
    theImgPath = theImg.getAttribute("src");
});

function changeImage(front, rear) {
    if (theImgPath === front) {
        alert("1");
        theImg.src = rear;
        alert("2");
    } else if (theImgPath === rear) {
        alert("3");
        theImg.src = front;
        alert("4");
    } else {
        alert("else..");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pic_box">
                    <img 
                        onclick="changeImage('<%#  GetFileURL(Eval("ImageFront"))%>', '<%#  GetFileURL(Eval("ImageRear"))%>')" 
                        id="imgCh_Front" alt="" class="ImageCh" src='<%# GetFileURL(Eval("ImageFront"))%>' />
                    <div class="ico">
                        <span class="fa fa-photo"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade"></div>
                </div>
```

function

```
 Public Shared Function GetFileURL(fileID As String) As String
        Dim fileInfo = GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(fileID))
        ' return a bad or default image url as appropriate
        If fileInfo Is Nothing Then
        Else
            Return GetUrl(fileInfo)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: I think you are missing src in 
else if (document.getElementById("imgCheque_Front") = imgRear) {

It should be else if (document.getElementById("imgCheque_Front").src = imgRear) {

Comment: You are using variable assignment `=` in you if block when you need to use comparison operator `==`.

Comment: @scrappedcola If I use == then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: can you try putting alert of current, imgFront and imgRear. There seems some minor mistake which you can detect by putting alert of these values.

@srappedcola is right, you will have to use == or ===. When you say it is not working at all, it is because when you use = it always enters into the first if condition but it doesn't mean that if condition is actually returning TRUE.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET But, in JavaScript, a single equal sign ASSIGNS a value, while a double (or triple) COMPARES values. If it's not working with == or ===, your problem is that the values don't match.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET In your code, you are making this call 5 times: `document.getElementById("imgCheque_Front").src`. My code does it once and stores that in a variable.  In your code, you introduce two new variables `imgFront` and `imgRear` that are simply assigned to the function's arguments of `front` and `rear`. There's no need to do that, just use the arguments. That's what my code does - - clean up your code and fix the omission of `.src` in one spot and adds `===` instead of `=` in another. My code does nothing to change what the input values to the function are.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET .... so wouldn't you think then that maybe the two values aren't equal???? I mean you are trying to compare the value of the image src to a variable right? Assignments are always true which is why it's always hitting the first if block. I think you really need to find a tutorial on program flow control if you don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET Why did you update your question to include the code that we both know wasn't working after I provided the correct solution (below)?  Anyone who comes along now and finds your question will be very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code fixes the two issues that you have, which were, not getting the source of the image in one case and not comparing the source, but rather assigning the source in another.

It also, removes the repeated calls to find the image's src:

```
<script>


    var theImg = null, theImgPath = null; 

    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
         theImg = document.getElementById("imgCheque_Front");
    });

    function changeImage(front, rear) {

        theImgPath = theImg.getAttribute("src");

        if (theImgPath  === front) {
            theImg.src = rear;
        } else if (theImgPath  === rear) {
            theImg.src = front;
        } else {
            alert("else..");
        }
    }
</script>
```

As an aside, your server-side code has some issues:

```
' The function is declared as returning a String
Public Shared Function GetFileURL(fileID As String) As String

    ' But here, your Dim doesn't have an "As" clause, which
    ' indicates that your are not working with Option Explicit
    ' and/or Option Strict turned on (very bad).

    ' What type does GetFile return? That's the type that fileInfo
    ' should be declared as.
    Dim fileInfo As ??? = GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(fileID))

    ' Here, you have an if/else with an empty true branch (not
    ' a good convention):
    If fileInfo Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Return GetUrl(fileInfo)
    End If

    ' How about this instead of all that above code:
    If Not GetFile(Convert.ToInt32(fileID)) Is Nothing Then
        Return GetUrl(fileInfo)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106039/discussion-between-scott-marcus-and-alwaysvbnet).

Comment: great recommendations